# Getting array of customizer settings

Tags: php, theme-customizer

I'm adding custom options to my theme using the customizer api. For example:

```
$wp_customize->add_setting( 'header_textcolor' , array(
    'default'   => '#000000'
) );

$wp_customize->add_setting( 'footer_textcolor' , array(
    'default'   => '#333333'
) );
```

Is it possible to return an array of all my custom settings from customizer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can get an array of all registered settings via `$wp_customize->settings()`. If you want to display them all you could do this:

```
if ( is_customize_preview() ) {
    global $wp_customize;
    $theme_mods = array();
    foreach ( $wp_customize->settings() as $setting ) {
        if ( 'theme_mod' === $setting->type ) {
            $theme_mods[ $setting->id ] = $setting->value();
        }
    }
    echo '<pre>' . json_encode( $theme_mods, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT ) . '</pre>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$all_settings = get_theme_mods();
print_r( $all_settings );
```

Comment: Note that `get_theme_mods()` is not currently compatible with the Customizer preview. See https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/24844

Comment: There is no mention in question where to get this settings.

Comment: The question is how to get all of the theme mods using the Customizer API.